# Why did my Feedburner feedcount reset to zero and how can I restore it?

Tags: wordpress, feeds, feedburner

I am using Google Feedburner for feed management of my Wordpress site.

I have around 6000 subscribers and have used its widget to display the count. Couple of days back suddenly, the feed count display is showing as zero. Internally when I login and verify the feed subscriber information is intact.

Only this count is shown as zero. What's going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to be a bug from Feedburner.

- [Google Feed Count Showing Zero ?](http://www.warriorforum.com/main-internet-marketing-discussion-forum/680347-google-feed-count-showing-zero.html)
- [Reasons Why Feedburner Count Shows Zero](http://www.mybloggertricks.com/2012/09/Feedcount-goes-zero.html)
- [Feedburner Reader Counter Drops to Zero.](https://getsatisfaction.com/technorati/topics/feedburner_reader_counter_drops_to_zero)

By the way, you should first check the [Feedburner blog](http://feedburnerstatus.blogspot.fr/2012/09/known-issue-subscriber-counts-and-stats.html) instead of posting here :)

> *Issue*: We have been encountering difficulties with our stats production pipeline for data representing Sept 19th and 20th, 2012. We are currently working to resolve the issue.

**Edit:**

Techcrunch just [posted an article](http://techcrunch.com/2012/09/24/feedburner-experiencing-stat-issues-api-to-shut-down/) about that.

> Feed stats, one of FeedBurner‘s main features, is currently broken, and Google quietly wrote a shutdown notice for the API. FeedBurner is a product that has been neglected by Google over the years. Yet, as the dominant product to manage RSS feeds, many developers count on it and expect it to be reliable. The future of the service remains unsure and a service shutdown is not out of the equation.

Comment: I should have gone there, missed it

Answer (score 2):

Feedburner blog may be shut down too..

Facts:

1. The counters are broken for everyone since about 9mp US eastern Sept 20th
2. Feeds are still currently being served
3. We don’t know whether this is temporary or not
4. The awareness API is being shut down Oct 20th.
5. If accurate stats are important, switch:

   1. Why: http://www.feedblitz.com/feedburner-shut-down-the-facts-and-tales-from-the-front-line/
   2. How: http://www.feedblitz.com/the-feedburner-migration-guide/

How to back up your subscriber list...

Good practice to download the CSV of your subscribers as back-up.

To see all of your subscribers: Click on the Analyze tab in FeedBurner. On the top right corner, you should see a drop-down box with the date. Select "All Time" in the box, then go click subscribers on the left menu. When that page loads, make sure it still says "All Time" in the date box. If not select "All Time", then scroll down to  "FeedBurner Email Subscriptions". Click that, then click  Manage Your Email Subscriber List.

**Disclosure:** I work for FeedBlitz and we'd be happy to assist you with any support you need to migrate your feed and your email subscribers.

Comment: Feedburner is not shut down.